# Simple SQL inner join query - can't get working

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    SELECT ai.auction_item_id, ai.starting_bid, b.bid_amount, i.*
    FROM
    auction_item as ai, //Table contains auction specific details about the item
    item as i //Table contains general details about the item
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT auction_item_id, bid_amount
            FROM bid xb //Table contains bids on item
            ORDER BY amount DESC
            LIMIT 1 ) b 
     ON b.auction_item_id = ai.auction_item_id
    WHERE
    ai.auction_id = 4 AND
    i.id = ai.listings_id

    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 4
```

Currently with the above query I am able to get 4 random items from the current active auction (auction #4). But they are all currently coming back with the same highest bid amount (from the inner join). Each item should have its own highest bid amount (from inner join) - unless that item has no bids then it should be 0 (or something)

What am I doing wrong here?
The bid table has a row for every bid placed thus the LIMIT 1 and order by desc in the inner join, as I want the highest bid for every item in the outer section. (if there is a bid that is).

Thanks

Comment: Currently only 1 of the 10 items has bids - so I think any item without a bid just is getting the highest bid of that 1 item with bids. So it needs to return 0 if no bids in that inner join. I think that would be the solution maybe

Comment: Scratch that, even if another item has bids - it just pulls the highest existing bid and uses that on all items (even items that have bids) :(

Comment: Your inner join table has no reference to the outer table, So it just gets you the same max bid_amount for all (outer) items. Currently testing a possible solution.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking something along those lines - thought that is what I though the "ON b.auction_item_id = ai.auction_item_id" was doing.

Comment: Everything behind the `on` is the link between the tables. But your table itself has no reference to the outside. Run the the query with the bid-table alone and see your result. You get one row with the maximum amount in the whole bid-table.

Comment: Question - do you want 4 random bids for the item, or do you need to randomly order the 4 highest bids for the item?

Comment: Stuart - I need 4 random items in the auction - and their highest bids

Comment: in the bid table, is there a difference between amount and bid_amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a sub-query. You geht a `0` if there a no entries in the bid-table because of the `coalesce`.

```
SELECT 
    ai.auction_item_id, ai.starting_bid, 
    Coalesce((SELECT max(xb.bid_amount)
              FROM bid xb
              WHERE xb.auction_item_id = ai.auction_item_id), 0) AS bid_amount,
    i.*
FROM auction_item AS ai
INNER JOIN item AS i ON i.id = ai.listings_id
WHERE ai.auction_id = 4 
ORDER BY Rand()
```

Comment: a subquery needlessly overcomplicates something that can be performed with a simple join and aggregation

Comment: I'm getting an error: #1054 - Unknown column 'bid_amount' in 'field list'

Comment: Whoops. Forgot that MySql doesn't know the `fieldName =` syntax. It`s now working with the right `AS bid_amount`.

Comment: That is what I was thinking the problem was. Yeap, that worked beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT ai.auction_item_id, ai.starting_bid, b.bid_amount, max(bid_amount)
    FROM auction_item as ai
      inner join bid b
        on ai.auction_item_id = b.auction_item_id
      inner join items i
        on i.id = ai.listings_id
    where ai.auction_id = 4
```

Adding your table schema to the question will help

**EDIT**:

```
SELECT ai.auction_item_id, ai.starting_bid, IFNULL(max(bid_amount), 0) max_bid
        FROM auction_item as ai
          left join bid b
            on ai.auction_item_id = b.auction_item_id
          inner join items i
            on i.id = ai.listings_id
        WHERE ai.auction_id = 4
        GROUP BY ai.auction_item_id
```

Here you go, including no bid items.

Let me know if i have the fiddle wrong: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0eae7/2

Comment: Thanks, that only pulls the item with the highest bid. 
I need all items listed (in auction 4) including their respective highest bids (or 0 if no high bids)

Comment: @Martin fixed to requirements?

Comment: Thanks, but the edit is still only pulling items that have bids - but is doing so correctly. Any item with no bid (nothing in the bid table) is being ignored.

Comment: How does my data structure in the fiddle differ from yours? in the fiddle it successfully shows the item with two bids, and the item with no bids

Comment: can i ask if you looked at my fiddle - the results are what you're asking for in that? an answer using a subquery is almost always suboptimal compared to one that uses joins

Comment: There is nothing wrong using a subquery as long as it gets you the result you're searching for.

Comment: thanks to the query optimizer, joins are generally more performant than subqueries - so yes, 'as long as it gets the answer' is not always suitable for database queries.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems:

- as per Hockenberry, cross joining to a derived table with `LIMIT 1` will just repeat the highest bid each time, and worse, it isn't filtered, so it will be the highest bid for *any* auction which will be joined out if the row isn't for the current `auction_item_id`. Move the LIMIT to the outer query.
- You'll want to use a `LEFT JOIN` to return a row even if there are no bids.
- You'll also need to `INNER JOIN` the `auction_item` to the `item` (your initial query won't run)

<del>SELECT ai.auction_item_id, 
           ai.starting_bid, 
           COALESCE(b.bid_amount, 0) as bid_amount,
           i.*
        FROM auction_item as ai
        INNER JOIN 
          item as i
          ON i.id = ai.listings_id
        LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT auction_item_id, bid_amount
             FROM bid xb
             ORDER BY amount DESC) b 
         ON b.auction_item_id = ai.auction_item_id
        WHERE
          ai.auction_id = 4
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 4;

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28922/1)</del>

**Edit**

Apologies, initially, I didn't understand what you were trying to achieve. If you want just the top bid (or zero if no bids) for any 4 random `auction_items`, here's one way to do this, using 2 derived tables:

- Determine 4 random items
- Find the top bid for each `auction_items`
- `LEFT JOIN` the two derived tables together

.

```
SELECT items.auction_item_id, IFNULL(topBids.amount, 0) as topBid
FROM
(SELECT auction_item_id
   FROM auction_item
   ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 4
) items
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT b.auction_item_id, b.amount
   FROM bid b
   GROUP BY b.auction_item_id
   ORDER BY amount DESC) topBids
 ON items.auction_item_id = topBids.auction_item_id;
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28922/10)

Comment: how is that close? he wants the max bid per auction item, and the first result of your fiddle shows a single auction item 4 times?

Comment: I was reading the OP's code, rather than his requirement. I had initially misinterpreted his requirement as any 4 bids on a single item (`ai.auction_id = 4`). The edit addresses the OP's comment `- I need 4 random items in the auction - and their highest bids`